# Change color of histogram bins at the same x value across facet panels?

Tags: ggplot2, histogram, bioinformatics

I am showing the number of variants at each position in different types of datasets: experimental and natural and colony morphotype data. I want to make the bins translucent that aren't at the same position within the facets, alpha = .5, and the bins that are the same position across facets to have full alpha=1. Each bin represents one position. So, if there is a bin at position 40200 in experiment, natural, and colony morphotype, I want that bar to have an alpha of 1, and all the other bars to have an alpha of .5.

This is my code:

`ggplot(dps_plot_expanded, aes(position, fill= variant)) + geom_histogram(position = "stack", binwidth = 5)+ theme_bw() + facet_wrap(~type, dir = "v", scales= "free_y") + ggtitle("dps biofilm") + theme_bw() + theme(text=element_text(size=20))`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable if the condition is met and then use this variable to determine the alpha level.

```
dps_plot_expanded <- dps_plot_expanded %>% 
    mutate(variable = ifelse(condition, 
                             1, 0.5))
 
ggplot(dps_plot_expanded, aes(position, fill = variant, alpha = variable)) + 
  geom_histogram(position = "stack", binwidth = 5)+ theme_bw() + 
  facet_wrap(~type, dir = "v", scales= "free_y") + 
  ggtitle("dps biofilm") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(text=element_text(size=20))
```